# Examples of web-mapping for plantations

Tags: web-mapping, development

Is there any of you ever work to develop a web-mapping project for a plantation company? Or is there any such project published? If there is then :

1. Can you point where I can see an example of the published project?
2. What was the main goal of the application? is it only for viewing purpose or is it combined with reporting system?
3. What platform do you use? Free or Paid?

Best Regards,

Comment: What is a plantation company? It's hard to understand this question without knowing what this key word means.

Comment: For example is Oil Palm Plantation. A company that has a core bussines in planting and harvesting Oil Palm fruit.

Comment: Would it be anythig like GIS for vineyards?  For example, [this](http://www.vestra.com/project/gis/vineyard-and-winery-management.html) work done by Vestra Resources.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the purposes of the application. Do you need a management support application, or just a cadastral webmap?

Comment: That is why I'm asking, both are needed, but I haven't seen a good example. If I'm using available framework (like geomoose, p-mapper, etc) they all best for viewing purpose only.

Comment: We generally build ad-hoc solutions for specific agricultural needs, based on generic gis/webgis softwares and frameworks. I don't know if general purpose webgis DSS systems exist for plantations management...

Answer (score 0):

One example I have come across was displayed by a fellow student. His project was to survey, catalog and display trees data. Find it here: http://citytrees.ca/

His web-based application utilizes:

- Google Fusion Tables
- jQuery

Hope this helps! Not plantation company specific, but you can see the functionality of a relevant underlying database.